# What Regex for this?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to learn regular expression, because I can't do without them.

So, this is a list of different dimension patterns (for products to sale) :

- 40x30x75
- 46x38x23-27
- Ø30H30
- Ø25-18H27

So, what pattern to use to find each kind of dimensions ?

For example, now, I'm using this to find this kind of pattern 40x30x75, but it not works :

```
if(preg_match("#^[0-9][x][0-9][x][0-9]#", $dimension))
   echo "ok"
```

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following regex:

```
(^[0-9]+x[0-9]+x[0-9]+$)|(^[0-9]+x[0-9]+x[0-9]+-[0-9]+$)|(^Ø[0-9]+H[0-9]+$)|(^Ø[0-9]+-[0-9]+H[0-9]+$)
```

So:

```
if (preg_match("/(^[0-9]+x[0-9]+x[0-9]+$)|(^[0-9]+x[0-9]+x[0-9]+-[0-9]+$)|(^Ø[0-9]+H[0-9]+$)|(^Ø[0-9]+-[0-9]+H[0-9]+$)/", $dimension))
   echo "ok";
```

It probably can be simplified even more, maybe someone would want to have a go at that?

By the way, did you know about a website called [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) it allows you to test your regular expessions, it has been very useful to me whenever I work with regex's.

Comment: The usage of `+` is fine unless they want to find those with the exact format like `40x30x75`. Using `+` rather than `{2}` would allow `4x300x75555`. Either way, I'd use `\d` rather than `[0-9]`. Much shorter :)

Comment: Good thinking, I totally forgot about \d

Answer (score 1):

Your regex should be:

```
^[0-9]{2}x[0-9]{2}x[0-9]{2}$
```

`[0-9]` means a single character which is between 0 and 9. So, you either need to have two of those, or use a quantifier thing like `{2}`. Instead of `[0-9]` you could also use `\d`, meaning any digit. So, you could for example write:

```
^\d\dx\d\dx\d\d$
```

---

**Tip:** If you can't do without regular expressions, want to learn it and have an easier life, I can recommend you get [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/). Bought it for myself when I just got started, and it has helped me *a lot*.

Comment: Thanks for the website, very interesting. Concerning your regex : ^[0-9]{2}[x][0-9]{2}[x][0-9]{2}, it's not "target" exactly that I want. Indeed, I can get this kind of pattern : 24x10x5à10x14x12

Comment: Wasn't sure if you wanted to find them in larger text or match a string or what, so I just left the anchor you had there already. The `^` means that it should start there. Added a `$` meaning the text should end there. This means it should only match 00x00x00 and not 00x00x00x00. Also, you don't need to wrap the `x` in `[]`. You only need to use those if you want to allow more than one character in that spot.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is missing *quantifiers*, add a `+` sign behind the character classes in question to singal you're looking for one or more matches:

```
if(preg_match("#^[0-9]+x[0-9]+x[0-9]+#", $dimension))
   echo "ok"
```

By default it's looking for one character of the class only. Single characters do not need the character class (albeit it was not wrong). See the `x`'es in the example above.

Comment: Using `+` would match for example `4x300x7555` as well.

Comment: Sure, as written, one or more. That's only one of the many quantifiers to choose from.

Answer (score 0):

This will validate the first two:

```
^[0-9]+x[0-9]+x[0-9]+-?[0-9]*$
```